# How to build this SearchQuery in SharePoint 2013 Search Result Webpart?

Tags: search-results, search-query

My search query:

```
Path:{Site.URL} EventDateOWSDATE:{Today+4} OR EndDateOWSDate:{Today+4}
```

Does only return the events with an **Enddate** of **Today+4**.
But I want it, to show me "all the Events of Today+4 or all the Events that End on Today+4".

How do I have to build the query correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Path:{Site.URL} EventDateOWSDATE:{Today+4} -OR EndDateOWSDate:{Today+4}`

Comment: It's not working. Any other ideas?